# I am receiving an axios error of status 500

Tags: typescript, prisma, next.js13

```
"use client"

import useUpdateModal from '@/app/hooks/useUpdateModal'
import axios from 'axios'
import { error } from 'console'
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import qs from 'query-string'
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast'

interface MemberBoxProps{
  name?: string | null
  email?: string | null
  role?: string | null
  mobileNum?:string
  id: string
}

const MemberBox:React.FC<MemberBoxProps> =  ({
  name,
  email,
  role,
  mobileNum,
  id,
  
}) => {

 console.log(id)

  const router = useRouter()
 
  const updateModal = useUpdateModal()

  const params = useSearchParams()

  // const handleClick = useCallback(()=>{
  //     let currentQuery = {}
  //     if(params)
  //     {
  //       currentQuery = qs.parse(params?.toString())
  //     }

  //     const updatedQuery:any={
  //       ...currentQuery,
  //       memberId:id
  //     } 
  //     if(params?.get('memberId')===id)
  //     {
  //       delete updatedQuery.memberId
  //     }

  //     const url = qs.stringifyUrl({
  //       url:'/users/',
  //       query:updatedQuery
  //     },{skipNull:true})
  //     router.push(url)
  // },[id,params,router])



  const handleDelete = async (memberId: string) => {
    try {
       axios.delete(`/api/delete?memberId=${memberId}`)
       .then(()=>toast.success("Team Member Deleted Successfully"))
       .finally(()=>router.refresh())
      
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Something went wrong");
    }
  };


   

  

  

  return (
    <div className="w-[300px] h-[350px] bg-white rounded-lg shadow-sm border-[1px] m-5 flex flex-col items-center justify-center cursor-pointer" >
      <div className=" flex flex-col  justify-between items-center gap-6">
        <div className="flex gap-4">
          <p>Name</p>
          <p>{name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex gap-4">
          <p>Email</p>
          <p>{email}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex gap-4">
          <p>Role</p>
          <p>{role}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex gap-4">
          <p>Mobile Number</p>
          <p>{mobileNum}</p>
        </div>

        <div className='flex gap-[60px]'>
          <button onClick={()=>handleDelete(id)} className='bg-sky-500 px-2 py-2 rounded-full'>
            Delete
          </button>

          <button onSubmit={()=>updateModal.onOpen} className='bg-sky-500 px-2 py-2 rounded-full'>Update</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MemberBox
```

this is my component in nextjs 13.3.1
and have a delete route in api/delete/route.ts

delete route file

```
    
import prisma from '@/app/libs/prismadb';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

interface IParams {
  memberId?: string;
}

export async function DELETE(
  req: Request,
  {params}:{params:IParams}
) 
{
 
  if(req.method!=='DELETE') 
  {
    return NextResponse.json({"message":"Method Not Allowed"})
  }

  const {memberId} = params

  try {
    await prisma.teamMember.delete({
      where: { id: memberId },
    });

      return NextResponse.json({"message":"Deleted SucessFully"})
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
      return NextResponse.json({"message":"Method Not Allowed"})
  }
}
```

I want to perform a delete operation, but I get a status 500 internal server error. Please help me to fix it. I tried by placing the route file in `api/delete/[memberId]/route.ts` but then I get a 404 not found axios error